# Is there any way to use instances using Array modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

i'm duplicating an object with Array but the object itself has a lot of geometry, so my computer slows down a lot, is there any solution to this, like adding more ''copies'' as instances?

Thanks in regard.

Comment: Copying with `Alt`+`D` should work to a degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a ***Simplify*** option. Check the *Simplify* box in *Scene header* and reduce the subdivisions to 2, 1 or 0. It may help you.

[image]